# How to use value from html form as css's url?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

HTML

```
<form>
<select name="1stban">
  <option value="puck.png">puck</option>
  <option value="antimage.png">antimage</option>
  <option value="abadon.png">abadon</option>
  <option value="slark.png">slark</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Confirm Heroes">
</form>
<div class="ban"></div>
```

CSS

```
.ban {
    height:20.25px;
    width:36px;
    background-image: url(Heroes/"1stban value");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Is it possible to to change the div's background img/css url so as to display image based on user's chosen option in select?

Comment: can you use `js` ? I don't think if there is anyother way to do it. If yes, please add `js` tag to your question so I could add solution

Comment: I think you would need JavaScript to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you may need JavaScript or jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#1stban").change(function(){
    var selectedVal = $('#1stban').find(":selected").text();
        
        $('.ban').attr('style', 'background-image: url( http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1)' ); //this is for demo
        //uncomment the below line for your code
        //$('.ban').attr('style','background-image: url(Heroes'+selectedVal+')');
        
    });
});
```

```css
.ban {
    height:20.25px;
    width:36px;
    //background-image: url(Heroes/"1stban value");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<select id='1stban' name="1stban">
  <option value="puck.png">puck</option>
  <option value="antimage.png">antimage</option>
  <option value="abadon.png">abadon</option>
  <option value="slark.png">slark</option>
</select>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Confirm Heroes">
</form>
<div class="ban"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with Javascript. Use onchange listener on your select. In your javascript check which item is selected and gives to your div the css class with the image on background.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CSS [variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) and than create a Javascript function to listen to what is selected to replace the variable value to the selected [image](https://eager.io/blog/communicating-between-javascript-and-css-with-css-variables/). The links I provided give you a more detailed answer.
Here is a rough example of the needed code.

```
:root {
/* :root is a clever way of saying "the outer-most element" */

--selected-png: url(path to png); 
}
.ban {
height:20.25px;
width:36px;
background-image: var(--selected-png);
background-size: cover;
}
```

Javascript part:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input')
var areaFortheBackgroundImage = document.querySelector('ban')

input.addEventListener('change', function(){
areaFortheBackgroundImagge.style.setProperty('--selected-png', 
input.value)
})
```